# Limit of distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory

Let $T\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ be a distribution on the set of smooth functions of compact support $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$
 \forall_{g\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})}~|\langle T, g \rangle| \leq \textrm{const}\|\tilde{g}\|_1, 
$$
where $\tilde{g}$ is Fourier transform of $g$ and $\|\tilde{g}\|_1:=\int_\mathbb{R} |\tilde{g}(\omega)| \, d\omega$.

What might be said about the existence of the limit
$$
 \lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} \langle T, g_a \rangle.
$$
where $g_a(x):=g(ax)$.

Comment: It can be shown that $T$ has order at most one. If it is of order one, then the sup-norm of $g_a$ explodes, thus we can hope tho prove that the limit goes to infinity. The only problem now is to find such a $T$=). If $T$ has order zero, then the sequence $(T,g_a)$ is bounded and we can't really say what happens with the limit without going into finer details.

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty, I think, comes form building such a distribution $T$. One can take $T=\delta_0$. In this case $\langle T,g_a\rangle=g(0)$ is a constant sequence.

Another example would be to take $T\in L^1(\Bbb R)$. In this case $\langle T,g_a\rangle\to0 $ as $a\to\infty$.

One of the examples of such distributions of first order is $p.v.(1/x)$, however, since this distribution is homogenous, $$\langle  p.v.(1/x),g(ax)\rangle = \lim_{\varepsilon \to0}\int_{x\ge \varepsilon}\frac{g(ax)-g(-ax)}{x}dx=\lim_{\varepsilon \to0}\int_{y\ge a\varepsilon}\frac{g(y)-g(-y)}{y}dy = \langle  p.v.(1/x),g(x)\rangle,$$ hence the sequence is once again constant.

It would be interesting to a) build a non-homogenous distribution $T$ of first order satisfying the estimations in terms of $\|\hat g\|_1$; b) build such a distribution $T$ of zeroth order such the limit of $\langle T,g_a\rangle$ does not exist (or show that it always converges).